# contrast in lme4 (but not pairwise contrast)

Tags: r, lme4, contrast

I am trying to do some contrasts using a mixed model, but don’t know how to use it. I looked at one post about this question on this website. However, it doesn't seem to meet our case. We don't want pairwise contrast.

In my case, there are five treatments in my experiment. Let’s call them A, B, C, D, and E.

I have the following hypotheses:

the response to A will be higher than the average of B, C and D.
the response to A will be higher than E
the average response to B, C and D will be higher than E.
the model is being run in lme4 as a mixed model:

response (binomial, 0 or 1) ~ treatment (the 5 levels above) + (1|tape) + (1|round) + (1|location). Each treatment has six tapes. We have six locations. The experiment was conducted for two rounds.

Does anyone know how best to code this? I am able to do multiple contrasts, but I believe the power of this method is lower than ideal.

With thanks and best wishes,

Hao (my e-mail address: longy213@163.com; pls e-mail me if the data would be helpful).

Comment: This is a situation where I usually write out the linear combinations of coefficients for each group using a vector of 0/1's and then combine those as needed to answer your research questions.  A quick search didn't come up with any great examples of doing that, although [this link](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/testing_contrasts.htm) and [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/vignettes/contrast.pdf) might get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.